# Horizontal rule overlaps the number of results in Help Center search

Tags: bug, design, meta, help-center

If I [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=something) in the help center, number of results overlap hr.

> [image]

I think that it is a bug, because [I don't see it on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=something).

Comment: I think the positioning is intentional. It just needs a white background.

Comment: @Moose [Then perform this search on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=something).

Comment: SO uses a significantly different template all-around. Either way, there is a bug. I just don't know if it's a bad `margin` or lack of `background`.